# Web2py scheduler stopping the app from running

Tags: mysql, sqlite, scheduler, web2py, pymysql

I cann't get the scheduler run in my ubuntu or debian linux machines. Originally I had db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite') which causes a weird situation where the website becomes unavailable (the browser cannot establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1) but when I run the same app without scheduler (without -K appname), and check the app database, it shows that the scheduler task has been running successfully. What is causing connection to the server to break?
Second, I tried using pymysql or mysqldb instead of sqlite. but, I get this error "Error in URI 'pymysql' or database not supported" even without -K myapp option.

Comment: Perhaps SQLite is locking. Are you using `db.commit()` in your scheduler task code to commit and close the transaction? Regarding MySQL, do you have it installed and running on your system, with the appropriate connection string in your DAL setup?

Comment: I do not have db.commit(), but if I wait so much yes the error that SQLite is locking (I will add db.commit() after I figure out the resolution), is sqlite supposed to work if db.commit is not used?. I have mysql installed  (I have checked mysql, pymysql and mysqldb by creating databases) Are these databases all supposed to work? This is my string for mysql: db2=DAL('mysql://root:pass@localhost/testdb2'), I have created testdb2 before using it.

Comment: These are other strings I have tried to use: 
    # db2 = DAL('sqlite://scheduler_storage.sqlite')
    # db2 = DAL('pymysql://root:pass@localhost/testdb2')
    db2=DAL('mysql://root:pass@localhost/testdb2')

    # db2 = DAL('MySQLdb://root:pass@localhost/testdb2')
   # db2 = DAL('pymysql://root:pass@localhost/testdb1')

Comment: You always need to call `db.commit()` to commit changes. You don't have to do this within web2py app code in the context of an HTTP request because the web2py framework handles this automatically at the end of the request handling. But scheduler tasks do not run in the context of an HTTP request, so you must explicitly commit any transactions.

Comment: Sorry, that did not come right, I do not have any transaction to commit. My tasks.py is similar to the same as shown in https://vimeo.com/27478796:
def f():
a=2
return()
from gluon.scheduler import Scheduler
Scheduler(db,dict(our_function=f))

Comment: Again, when I run the app with scheduler option (-K my app), the scheduler is running but the browser cannot bring up the app (error:cannot establish connection). How do I know the schedule task was running? by going back and running the app without the scheduler option and looking at the task table and I see the task has been running successfully.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I had forgot that I need to run the server separately. The issue was not valid and disappeared after running web2py